# Should one put poster presentations on their CV in maths?

Tags: mathematics, cv, poster

I have presented posters at poster sessions at a few large conferences in pure mathematics. Is it worth putting these down on one's CV?

For context, I am a PhD student and have also given talks at several seminars and (smaller) conferences, so my CV is not especially in need of bulking up. Currently I do not have them on my CV. Moreover, my feeling is that posters in pure maths are not peer reviewed at all (in contrast to my impression of other areas), though I do not know this for definite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you are a PhD student (in math; I am also in math), I think you probably should put this on your CV.  Going to conferences shows some professionalism and interest, and giving poster presentations does too.  I don't want to suggest that this will be a key piece of information for your job search and/or early career, but...it certainly can't hurt.  You may want to take them out later when your CV has filled out in other ways.

The fact that they are not peer reviewed does not seem directly relevant to me, as long as you don't lump them together with publications (why would you?) or suggest in some way that they are something they were not.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is the practice I've seen in many other STEM fields as well... list all your conference presentations, posters, white papers, etc. on your resume in their own separate sections.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the peer-reviewing process, in conferences in my field (civil engineering), sometimes we receive 100-200 papers. After the review process is over, typically, the top 10% get to be presented in key sessions. Then, top 30-50% of accepted papers will be presented in regular sessions. Finally, the rest will be presented as posters (due to lack of time/rooms) or declined! So, you can say that there is some sort of a peer reviewing process involved.

In my case, I have always added the posters under "Presentations and Poster contributions in Conferences" section in my resume (and  I can assure you that I really do not need to do that). This section falls right after "Articles published in conference proceedings". I do not see the point of doing some work and spending time on preparing a poster or an abstract and not take credit for it. Every small contribution is valuable. I doubt that whoever is interested in your resume will consider posters as a major contribution. Most likely they will  skim through it or completely skip it. Peer reviewed journal articles are the most important part of a researcher's career (in my field).

Comment: This question is specially about conventions in *mathematics*.

Comment: I understand, and I have mentioned that in my answer. However, from interaction with some colleagues in different departments, it seems that many fields tend to operate [somehow] in a similar fashion. P.S., He did not use "conventions" but rather 'conferences".

Comment: I meant "conventions" in the sense of "standards", and he/she specifically said in the question that he believes mathematics to be different from other fields in this respect.

Comment: As far as I know, things work completely differently in mathematics. You don't send papers to a conference for peer review, you send them to a journal. Talks aren't necessarily about a single paper, and aren't really peer-reviewed before the presentation itself. There may be conferences where some sort of peer review occurs, but I've never heard of one (though I'm just a PhD student so I don't claim to know everything about the field, maybe they exist, but the point is they're not the norm at all).

Comment: Thanks for shining in. I just want to clear that peer reviewing for possible publication in a journal is way different than that used in reviewing a submitted paper to a conference. Peer reviewing in a conference simply means that such paper fits the conference theme, has valuable results and is worthy of being displayed/discussed.

Comment: The Fire Guy: What you say in your last comment is not true in all fields.  For instance, in many branches of computer science, conferences have essentially replaced journals as being the most prestigious publication venue, and there are conferences such that submitting a paper to that conference corresponds to submitting to a top journal in another field.

Comment: On the other hand, the above comments about mathematics are completely correct: at a mathematics conference (well, > 99% of the time; I was recently involved with a rare exception) one does not submit **anything** in advance of giving a talk.  Moreover a conference talk may correspond to a number of papers which is greater than, equal to, or less than one, and these papers may already have been published, may be publicly available but not published, submitted but not yet available, not yet written, never be written, etc.

Comment: I understand Pete. CS is different than civil engineering so is mathematics. Perhaps I should write civil engineering in every comment I write. One more thing, even in talks (from keynote speakers for an example), you do not need to submit anything in advance. Talks/discussions are different than submitted papers. You submit papers, and after being reviewed, they will be accepted to be presented as key-papers, papers or posters.

Comment: @The Fire Guy: I will clarify my last comment.  In most math conferences, before the conference itself there is no academic material submitted by anyone or refereed and reviewed by anyone, so (it follows that) none of the scheduled activities depend on responses to pre-submitted material.   So your answer "So, you can say that there is some sort of a peer reviewing process involved." is unfortunate advice: with very high probability there was no peer reviewing process done in the OP's case, so he cannot say that.

Comment: @peter, thanks for your comment. My full comment is "Regarding the peer-reviewing process, in conferences in my field **(civil engineering)**, ...... So, you can say that **there is some sort of a peer reviewing process involved**." I hope this clears out any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Since you are answering the OP's question, I had assumed that the quoted sentence was addressed to the OP and his situation.